# Decorate Function Call - Trying to Remove Nullability from Signature

Tags: typescript

### Here is the corresponding [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhmMcoGEAWaDmApgCo4wDOAYuBADwCCAfABQBuAXIs-YgD6JgQAGyEBKPl2YhO3CYJGjxAXkZce-eWMWIA3gChEhxAHpjyNBijI8YIoihlyiAEZwAJgE89AXz17QkLAI5uiYuAQkjgDKMPhgKFAgAE6EDCwciOqS0pnKqvTa%20kYmZqhIEDZ2DhQu7l7FZZbhtpEU1JBpbKIA3D5%20AdDw5RZhla3kMXEJyYQATJ0ZWcxSnAWIKrniRUamIdYR9o61ngZGMMBcUB4ADoRwF6zrSkqIAEQDQWCvW6fFho2jCKkNo0TpsDKyDTCLTrVRscGKHq-RDeRCEITkQi6ZENEbYMbAqigphdXrFXy%20IA).

---

Here is a function which I cannot change at all:

```
function cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v: (A | null) | ((u: (A | null)) => (A | null))) {
    // cannot change this body
}
```

Now I created a function which literally has the same signature as `cannotChangeThisFunc` but disallows all `null` values:

```
function cannotChangeThisSignature<A>(v: A | ((u: A) => A)) {
  cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(/* ... */);
}
```

The goal is that a call to `cannotChangeThisSignature` should invoke `cannotChangeThisFunc` with the same value. The following does not work:

```
function cannotChangeThisSignature<A>(v: A | ((u: A) => A)) {
    // can change this body
    cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v);
}
```

Neither does this (besides the fact that would be runtime checking and should be compile time checking):

```
function cannotChangeThisSignature<A>(v: A | ((u: A) => A)) {
    // can change this body
    if (typeof v === "function") {
        cannotChangeThisFunc<A>((vv: (A | null)) => (v(vv)));
    } else {
        cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v);
    }
}
```

Can someone elaborate please?

---

### Here is the corresponding [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhmMcoGEAWaDmApgCo4wDOAYuBADwCCAfABQBuAXIs-YgD6JgQAGyEBKPl2YhO3CYJGjxAXkZce-eWMWIA3gChEhxAHpjyNBijI8YIoihlyiAEZwAJgE89AXz17QkLAI5uiYuAQkjgDKMPhgKFAgAE6EDCwciOqS0pnKqvTa%20kYmZqhIEDZ2DhQu7l7FZZbhtpEU1JBpbKIA3D5%20AdDw5RZhla3kMXEJyYQATJ0ZWcxSnAWIKrniRUamIdYR9o61ngZGMMBcUB4ADoRwF6zrSkqIAEQDQWCvW6fFho2jCKkNo0TpsDKyDTCLTrVRscGKHq-RDeRCEITkQi6ZENEbYMbAqigphdXrFXy%20IA).

Comment: I'm confused. Is the idea to just circumvent type-checking and assert confidently that all values are non-null? If so, `v as any` gets you all the way there.

Comment: Presumably `cannotChangeThisFunc`'s body possibly calls its input with `null`, if its input is a function, right? That's what the call signature implies. But if `cannotChangeThisSignature()` passes its input to `cannotChangeThisFunc()`, then you can call `cannotChangeThisSignature((x: string) => x.toUpperCase())` and cause a runtime error, which is what the compiler is warning you about.  Indeed there are quite a few potential problems with those call signatures (nothing stops `A` from being a function type itself, so checking for functions doesn't do anything). See [here](//tsplay.dev/WPzLZN)

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining more thoroughly; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. A function given to the one with `null` (`cannotChangeThisFunc`) has to be able to deal with `null` inputs, but the function of the non-null version (`cannotChangeThisSignature`) cannot do that.
2. Type `A` can be a function itself, so `(typeof v === "function")` does not guarantee that it is a function of type `A => A`

The first one you can handle by wrapping the function. This is fine, since `cannotChangeThisSignature` does not receive `null` input. However, the second one I don't think you can solve except telling typescript that `v` must be `A => A`. So basically cheat a bit:

```js
type Fun<A> = ((u: A) => A) // just for readability

function cannotChangeThisSignature<A>(v: A | Fun<A>) {
  if (typeof v === "function"){
    const wrappedV = wrapWithNullHandler(v as Fun<A>) // read v as A => A
    cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(wrappedV);
  } else {
    cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v);
  }
}

function wrapWithNullHandler<A>(fun: Fun<A>): Fun<A|null> {
  return (aOrNull: (A|null)) => (aOrNull === null) ? null : fun(aOrNull)
}
```

That means that you could do

```
const f = () => 42
cannotChangeThisSignature(f) // no ts error but not right either
```

and you might get an exception. I don't think that is a limitation in typescript, but a language problem, as it is not possible to discern at runtime if a given function is `A => A` or something else. That means that there is no clean way to this at all.

But when cheating is the only solution anyway, and handling the `null`s isn't really necessary, I would just skip that step:

```
function cannotChangeThisSignature<A>(v: A | Fun<A>) {
  if (typeof v === "function"){
    cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v as Fun<A|null>); // it' ok, ts
  } else {
    cannotChangeThisFunc<A>(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pointing out the 2 problems was enough for me to realize my plan to decorate the call is trash and I should change my overall design. Thank you, I absolutely missed those problems but they are now pretty obvious to me.